# Sort data by date

Tags: java, collections, comparator

```
name=dfd: desc=dfgdf: startDate=12/05/2016: endDate=04/06/2016:
tags=sff,sff: priority=5: status=new: actualEndDate=null
```

I have above type of data in my file and I want to sort it by `startDate`.
What will be the logic?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create class say Data and then implement Comparable in that like:

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
     private String name;
     private Date startDate;
     ...//other fields
     ...//getter setter
     public int compareTo(Data otherData) {
          return this.startDate.compareTo(otherData.startDate);
     }
}
```

Then read and create a list of records like:

```
List<Data> dataList = ....
//read file and add data to list
Collections.sort(dataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the characteristics of your dataset and what you want to do with it afterwards. If you just want to have it sorted by date, then @SMA's answer is good. You might also want to, assuming start dates are unique, use the date as a key to find a particular record: look into `SortedMap<Date,T>` if that's your preferred route.